# Writing an equation in one line

Tags: equations, fractions

```
\[ f(x)=\frac{\beta}{t} \]\[\frac{t}{\alpha} \]
```

I'm trying to multiply two fractions `(beta/t)(t/alpha)`, but for some reason it puts the second fraction in a line below the first and not in the same line.  How do I code it so it's in one line.

Comment: Just use one math environment `\[ f(x)=\frac{\beta}{t} \frac{t}{\alpha} \]`.

Answer (score 3):

If you want it shown as a multiplication
[image: ![enter image description here]

try either or mix parts of these

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\centering

$f(x)=\left({\beta}\slash{t}\right)\left({t}\slash{\alpha}\right)$

is equivalent to
\[ f(x)=\frac{\beta}{t} \times \frac{t}{\alpha} \]  

\end{document}
```

The simplest most compact form acceptable to many math inline equation editors producing a line similar to the first would likely just be

```
$f(x)=(\beta/t)(t/\alpha)$
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
Here the function is given by, $f(x)=\left(\dfrac{\beta}{t}\right)\left(\dfrac{t}{\alpha}\right)$, where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are variables.

\end{document}
```

Comment: As far as i understood a question, OP like to have displayed equation, which should be in one line (and not in two as is produced with her/his code). See @AboAmmar comment which gives the best suggestion (to my opinion, of course).

Comment: The question is a bit confusing. I thought it was for writing the equation in between the lines. This can be just achieved by putting the eqn using $eqn$. My bad @Zarko